# Want to display output in column wise in Linux Shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have printed my output in the below format.

```
last -w -F | awk '{print $1","$3","$5$6$7$8","$11$12$13$14","$15}' | tac
```

Now for the same output I want to display column wise. Can some one help me out here?

Comment: What do you mean "column wise" exactly? What have you tried? Have you tried `column`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the end: `| tr ',' '\t'`, like this:

```
last -w -F | awk '{print $1","$3","$5$6$7$8","$11$12$13$14","$15}' | tac | tr ',' '\t'
```

This will pipe your comma-delimited output to the [`tr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) utility and tell it to translate commas to tabs.

Comment: Thank you very much for prompt response.I want to add headers for the printed output,Can you help me how to do that. "USERNAME"  for $1 "HOSTNAME" for $3 "LOGIN_TIME" for  LOGOUT_TIME" for $5$6$7$8 and DURATION for $15.Thank you once again.